# How to specify float format in doctrine 1.2 schema?

Tags: php, floating-point, doctrine, schema

When I use such notation in doctrine 1.2 schema file `some_float_field: { type: float }` doctrine generates SQL for it `some_float_field FLOAT(18, 2)`

But I need more digits after decimal point, for example `FLOAT(18,10)`. Is there a way to specify float format in schema file or doctrine config ?

Do you possibly know what file in doctrine package generates sql from schema file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure about float, but for decimal it's

```
type: decimal(18)
scale: 10
```

float should be something similar I guess